# Have problem to introduce a file to python

Tags: python

I create a file on Desktop. My file is:  soheil.txt

But when I write this function on python it doesn't recognize It:

```
f=open('soheil.txt')
type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper')
```

I also tried this:

```
   f=open('C:\Users\Soheil_PC\Desktop\soheil.txt')
```

But neither works. why the type of the function is not 'file'?

Comment: Which is the error you get?

Comment: In Python2 the type is `file`, in Python3 it is `_io.TextIOWrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably following some tutorial for Python 2, in which:

```
f = open("test.txt")
type(f)
# <type 'file'>
```

Python 3 gives more information:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt")
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

You should find some up-to-date learning material!

Comment: Ok, So type    <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>    meaning it is file?

Comment: Yes, it's a 'file' - but you shouldn't really have to care about what type of object that exactly is, as long as you can use it the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

To open the file from a Windows path you need to escape backslash like

```
f=open('C:\\Users\\Soheil_PC\\Desktop\\soheil.txt')
```

Or to `r` before the path string

```
f=open(r'C:\Users\Soheil_PC\Desktop\soheil.txt')
```

Comment: I tried  both codes now, and it give the same type. and doesn't show type file

Comment: It's showing the type of the Python type object. you are looking to a method to return you txt?

Comment: No I watched a tutorial of python. that it introduce a file to python and after he writes   type(f)    python says <file> It seems It doesn't matter and both of them are files!

Comment: That is depending on the python version that you run the type from.

Answer (score 1):

[open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function is used for reading streams and has multiple modes. Default mode is `r` and it is for reading text streams. Base class for text stream is [TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) and [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) inherits it. It expected to see the result type of the `open()` as `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`.

> If you are using python 2 it can be printed as `<type 'file'>`

Answer (score 0):

The open() function opens a file, and returns it as a file object.
A file object allows us to use, access and manipulate all the user accessible files. One can read and write any such files.